# WPF - Does HwndSource have to be disposed?

Tags: wpf, interop, idisposable

I'm using `HwndSource` in a WPF window, which is not the main window, in order to hook a window procedure (WndProc) to receive some messages:

```
WinSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
WinSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
```

`HwndSource` implements `IDisposable`. MSDN is not clear about when/should I dispose it. The docs of [HwndSource.FromHwnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.fromhwnd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains the technique above:

> You can use this method to return an HwndSource for a window that is not explicitly an interoperation window. The procedure for this is:
>
> 1. Create a WindowInteropHelper instance (providing the main Window as a constructor parameter).
> 2. Get the value of the Handle property from that WindowInteropHelper instance.
> 3. Pass that HWND value as a parameter to FromHwnd.

And then:

> This technique can be useful if you then want to add general AddHook message processing to the window. However, **whenever you create an HwndSource, you are also responsible for destroying it. This is true even if the Application object for an application HwndSource is disposed.**

(the emphasis is mine)

However, at the [HwndSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class doc, we see:

> **Object Lifetime**
>
> An HwndSource is a regular common language runtime (CLR) object, and its lifetime is managed by the garbage collector. Because the HwndSource represents an unmanaged resource, HwndSource implements IDisposable. [...] Calling Dispose explicitly from the interoperating code might be necessary for certain interoperation scenarios.

And regarding the hook:

> The actual hooks are held by a weak reference. Therefore, make sure that you manage the lifetime of your hook delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a full answer to this, but based on recent experience I can say that you should not dispose the `HwndSource` object too soon - specifically, not at all until the window it refers to is closed.

I was just debugging a scenario that was done like this:

```
using(var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(window.HWnd()))
{
     source.AddHook(hook);
}
```

The result of this was that the window became nonfunctional (no longer processing messages) right after the source was disposed.

Looking briefly into the reference source for `FromHwnd()`, it seems that it will always return you the same object for the same window. I think this is why you cannot dispose `source` just because your own code is done with it. Apparently `HwndSource.Dispose()` doesn't just clean up the `HWndSource` object, but some of the unmanaged window itself.

Having noticed this, now I also see the HWndSource [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsource) says:

> Synchronously calling Dispose immediately destroys the Win32 window

which seems to be what I've observed.

Comment: That's correct.  The `HwndSource` owns the `HWND`, which is the actual window.  The `Window` class only represents the content of the window, not the title bar / resize borders.